# Azure AD authentication with Username and Password and also have MFA

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, console-application, webapi

I implemented Azure AD Authentication using MSAL (RPOC) and .net 4.6.1 . I am able to authenticate the user if the user's MFA isn't enabled. If it is enabled then I receive an Error

```
**Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.**
```

This is the code I am using.

```
 public async Task<string> ValidateUserAsync()
    {

        string authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenant);
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
        IPublicClientApplication app;
        app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                  .WithAuthority(authority)
                  .Build();
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())  
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, securePassword).ExecuteAsync();
        return result.IdToken;
    }
```

How do I implement MFA? Like receive sms of code and pass the same to this?
I will be having my own UI to accept the code

Comment: you can get help from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.
In order for user to do MFA, they must do it on the Microsoft login page.
This is one of the limitations of the ROPC authentication flow.
I recommend you use a different flow and do not collect the user password.